# How to mount host folder to guest, while keeping the contens in guest folder?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount, guest-additions

Sorry for the confusing title, I tried to make sense of it but it didn't work.

Say, I have a windows folder called 'share' in '`C:/share`' and in linux I have a folder in `/var/www` normally, if there are contents in `share` but not in `/var/www` I would do `mount -t vboxsf share /var/www` and it works, but in this case, there is already content in `/var/www` and `C:/share` is empty.

If I ran the same command, the mount would work, but everything in /var/www would disappear, my question is how to mount it while keeping the contents in `/var/www`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense at the file system level.  You Are asking Linux to merge the contents of directories in two file systems into a single view. This can't work.  Ex: how would Linux know where to write a new file?

Comment: I am simply saying that I have a linux image that comes with a data already in /var/www I want to share `/var/www` with my `c:/share`, if I do `mount -t vboxsf share /var/www` the content in `/var/www` disappears, but I need it to say so I can access in windows by going to C:/share

Comment: According to the docs, virtualBox doesn't support this with its additions. However, you could share the folder via samba and access it from the host that way.

Comment: you should update your question to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You said one was empty. I am wondering, does it exist? Because this sounds similar to a symlink in *nix systems. I have done something like this several times in Virtual Box...I am guessing there is more to the story that you are telling, though.

Comment: I am simply saying that I have a linux image that comes with a data already in /var/www I want to share `/var/www` with my `c:/share`, if I do `mount -t vboxsf share /var/www` the content in `/var/www` disappears, but I need it to say so I can access in windows by going to C:/share